# how to select a value from Auto Suggestion list in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to select 1st auto suggested value after fill the data but it is not working for me
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtFrom']").send_keys("Delhi, India",Keys.DOWN))`

I tried using both way `Keys.TAB` and `Keys.DOWN` but when I am using this that time even data is not getting filed in textbox and error is coming
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtFrom']").send_keys("Delhi, India",Keys.DOWN)) NameError: name 'Keys' is not defined`

Here is my Complete Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Users/prash/Desktop/WebScrape/selenium/chromedriver' 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(10) 
driver.maximize_window()
url = 'http://tis.nhai.gov.in/tollplazasonmap?language=en'
driver.get(url) 
embed = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('embed') 
driver.switch_to.frame(embed) 
element = driver.find_element_by_id('tollstation') 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtFrom']").send_keys("Delhi, India",Keys.DOWN))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtTo']").send_keys("Bangalore",Keys.DOWN))
element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='showstation']/p[7]/a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element2)
```

Comment: Is sending the 'down' key enough? I would assume you need to send an enter key after moving down to the highlighted selection.

Comment: Yes, after moving down and select 1st auto suggestion we can send enter..
but whenever I am using `Keys.DOWN` or `Keys.TAB` or `Keys.ENETR` even data is not getting filled in textbox

Comment: Did you send both Keys.DOWN and Keys.ENTER?

Comment: Yes, I send both and getting error 

`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtFrom']").send_keys("Delhi, India",Keys.ENTER))
NameError: name 'Keys' is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To able to use [`Keys` module](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.keys) you should import it first as

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

After that you can use in your code `Keys.TAB`, `Keys.DOWN`, etc

Comment: Thanks, Data is getting filled in 1st textbox and `Keys.TAB` woking. But in 2nd textbox data is not getting filled `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtTo']").send_keys("Bangalore",Keys.TAB)`  and throwing an error `value = method(self._driver)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: I guess this is because you use `ExplicitWait` incorrectly. Try `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='txtFrom']"))).send_keys("Delhi, India",Keys.DOWN)`

Comment: after getting the data in both textbox, this is my search button
`element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='showstation']/p[7]/a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element2)` 
but it not getting click

Comment: Try `element2 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Search"‌​)` instead

Comment: The cursor is displaying still in 2nd textbox, is there any way to move cursor or any other solution ..